# Twilio caller whisper with the agents' name

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I'm trying to implement a callers' whisper. I want the caller to hear "You will be connected to {AGENT_NAME}." before the agent picks it up. I'm using TwiML to respond to incoming calls and also the hosted version of Twilio Flex.

The flow for the caller to end up in the queue is as simple as calling TwiML  but from there I don't seem to understand what I can do to make it work.

There is some scarce documentation on the subject here and there but no actual examples or any clues whatsoever.

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts

How can I implement a simple "You are about to connect to {AGENT_NAME}" whisper to the caller only before the agent picks up the call? Thanks

Comment: How does the TwiML look like you're returning? And how did you set up Twilio Flex?

Comment: @yvesonline TwiML is a simple <Enqueue> that puts callers into a workspace. What do you mean how I set up Twiliio Flex? Thanks

Comment: How do you currently connect the caller and the agent? You should be able to use the [redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call) which you already linked. Basically you point to an URL which returns TwiML which 1) looks up the agents name 2) forms a `<Say></Say>` with the agents name and then 3) connects the caller and the agent.

Comment: @yvesonline Thank you, the reservation is made by Twilio automatically. I tried to redirect the reservation once was made like you're suggesting but it led to some kind of an infinite loop. I followed this piece: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks#redirecting-call